# libusb mass storage works continuously

Tags: windows, libusb, usb-mass-storage

I'm writing and reading data on usb flash disc. Despite I free resources and call libusb_exit, USB disk's led continuously flashes and device gets heated after a while.

Moreover, this happens even if I close my application. It stops if I detach and reattach the device.

How can this happen, any thoughts? It seems the problem is driver based. I override the mass storage driver with Zadig.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking into it with an usb sniffer to find out what is transfered between the computer and the disk?

Comment: Good advice, thank you.